# eliminar necesidad de permisos en android

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

estoy intentando publicar mi primera app en Play, y me pide que además aporte una politica de privacidad ya que mi app utiliza permisos que requieren una política de privacidad:

> (android.permission.CAMERA, android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
>   android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS,
>   android.permission.READ_CONTACTS)

.

Algo he hecho mal, porque mi app no necesita ninguno de ellos: ni usa audio, ni camara, ni accede a contactos ni cuentas, ni a mi numero de telefono...
¿Como puedo eliminar la necesidad de estos permisos?
¿Simplemente elimino cada linea de "uses-permision" en Android manifest?
Gracias.

Comment: también depende de los plugins que uses, si usas firebase etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Últimamente se han cambiado algunas políticas en google play, se han agregado requerimientos e incluso la forma de subir las aplicaciones, (incluso alpha y beta), las politicas de privacidad son necesarias, pero si no se requieren los permisos que mencionas en tu aplicación ( te recomiendo los elimines y pruebes si en verdad no son requeridos para el correcto funcionamiento de tu aplicación) simplemente eliminalos del archivo manifesto: `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Cuando subas el .apk, Google Play detectará que no se tienen especificados estos permisos, por lo tanto no te requerirá especificar políticas de privacidad.

Comment: Gracias!!!Exactamente que líneas he de quitar?No quisiera meter la pata.

Comment: Agrega tu androidmanifest.xml , si lo deseas oculta el paquete de la aplicación.

Answer (score 1):

Sí, si tu aplicación no necesita usar la cámara, las grabaciones de audio ni ninguno de los permisos que has mencionado anteriormente simplemente dirígete al archivo `Manifest.xml` y elimina las líneas que no necesites en tu aplicación. Solo deberías de mantener los permisos que realmente si que se vayan a utilizar en tu app.

De esta manera, tu aplicación no pedirá esos permisos al iniciarse.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.
he eliminado de AndroidManifest.xml. las lineas de "uses permision" que no necesitaba y todo correcto, la app funciona bien y ya no se exige politica de privacidad desde google play.
De nuevo gracias, un saludo.